# pip Installation Error with Python path configuration and Fatal error in launches

Tags: python, pip

I tried to Download PIP I am not sure if I successfully did it or not but I accidentally download it 2 times I tried to delete it and reinstall but this code popped up in CMD instead.

```
C:\Users\pow>python get-pip.py
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python310.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\pow\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PYTHON310\\Lib\\',
    'C:\\Users\\pow\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PYTHON310\\DLLs\\',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\Lib\\',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\DLLs\\',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Python310',
  ]
```

```
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00005fb4 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Typed this in cmd twice and suddenly I cannot run `pip`:

```
python get-pip.py
```

after that when I run pip help it says

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\pow\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON310\python.exe" 
 "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" help': The system cannot find 
the file specified.
```

What should I do?

Comment: C:\Users\pow\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON310\python.exe and C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python.exe shown .. maybe start be removing both python installations, install a fresh one and start again ?

Answer (score -2):

you can try below solutions:

1. upgrade pip as `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. check environment if its activated
3. use `python -m pip install package_name` if `pip install package_name` not working